# ggplot2: Fix colors to factor levels with long factor names

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am creating several figures with ggplot2 and want to assign fixed colors to different groups. To do so, I am using the approach shown in question [ggplot2: Fix colors to factor levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43440068/ggplot2-fix-colors-to-factor-levels) as provided by [alistaire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4497050/alistaire).

That is, I defined my own custom scale as follows

```
library(ggplot2)

scale_fill_ind <- function(...){
    ggplot2:::manual_scale(
        'fill', 
        values = setNames(c('green', 'blue', 'red', 'orange'), LETTERS[1:4]), 
        ...
    )
}

df1 <- data.frame(Value = c(40, 20, 10, 60), 
                  Type = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Type, y = Value, fill = Type)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    scale_fill_ind()

df2 <- data.frame(Value = c(40, 20, 60), 
                  Type = c("A", "B", "D"))

ggplot(df2, aes(x = Type, y = Value, fill = Type)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    scale_fill_ind()
```

However, in my own code, the factor names are significantly longer than just "A", "B",..., so that I have to "force" a linebreak in the legend with `str_wrap()` with a maximum of 25 characters per line.

This, however, avoids the colors to be assigned to my factors that have a linebreak. If I shorten the factor names, the approach works well. Do you have any idea, how I can assign fixed colors to my "long" factors names such that the approach above works?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am trying to replicate this problem but I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve. Having factor names longer than 25 chars is fine and using your code above they plot without issue; is the forced line-break purely for stylistic reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you could use `paste`:

```
library(ggplot2)

list_of_factors <- list(paste("Aaljdfgneopghpihj", "wgwgvldjnfgpwghiwg", sep = "\n"),
                     paste("Baodjfwapigaafgja", "3jgamdgvaksmngvaksn", sep = "\n"),
                     paste("Cskndvlsnvljengwlan", "kgaksnbvalsknbsfblskn", sep = "\n"),
                     paste("Dafsnjljbipenbvmdsvs", "mvslkbndfbkndfb", sep = "\n")) 

scale_fill_ind <- function(...){
  ggplot2:::manual_scale(
    'fill', 
    values = setNames(c('green', 'blue', 'red', 'orange'), list_of_factors), 
    ...
  )
}

df1 <- data.frame(Value = c(40, 20, 10, 60), 
                  Type = c(paste("Aaljdfgneopghpihj", "wgwgvldjnfgpwghiwg", sep = "\n"),
                           paste("Baodjfwapigaafgja", "3jgamdgvaksmngvaksn", sep = "\n"),
                           paste("Cskndvlsnvljengwlan", "kgaksnbvalsknbsfblskn", sep = "\n"),
                           paste("Dafsnjljbipenbvmdsvs", "mvslkbndfbkndfb", sep = "\n")))

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Type, y = Value, fill = Type)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_fill_ind()
```